# RXJS observable unsubscribe inner observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

After `this.route.params` is destroyed and `this.sub` is unsubscribed, `"interval run"` keeps logging. This was against my intuition that with one subscription, after an unsubscribe, everything should stop happening. What's happening here & what's the best way to deal with it? Should I add a takeUntil, or should I use something other than concatMap? (i'm polling for new photos)

```
 constructor(private authService:AuthService,
            private route:ActivatedRoute,
            private router:Router,
            private photosApi:PhotosApi) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params
        .switchMap(()=>{
            console.log('switchmap Ruun')
            return Observable.interval(2000).startWith(0).concatMap(()=>{
                console.log('interval run')
                return this.photosApi.apiPhotosGet(this.authService.getAuth(), 0, 40)
            })
        })
        .subscribe((data:PagedResultPatientPhotoModel) => {
                this.processPhotos(data)
            }).add(()=>console.log('unsubscribe happened'))
```

edit: I tried rewriting to make it cleaner,
the following with concatMap only does one call, i'm not sure why it stops working after the first call:

```
this.intervalSub = Observable.interval(3000).startWith(0).concatMap(()=>{
        console.log('getting photos interval', this.route.params)
        return this.route.params.switchMap(()=>{
            console.log('getting photos')
            return this.photosApi.apiPhotosGet(this.authService.getAuth(), 0, 40)
        })
    }).subscribe((data:PagedResultPatientPhotoModel) => {
                this.processPhotos(data)
            }).add(()=>console.log('unsubscribe happened'))
```

and the following with switchMap works as long as the api calls can run faster than 3000, otherwise they cancel each other:

```
this.intervalSub = Observable.interval(3000).startWith(0).switchMap(()=>{
        console.log('getting photos interval', this.route.params)
        return this.route.params.switchMap(()=>{
            console.log('getting photos')
            return this.photosApi.apiPhotosGet(this.authService.getAuth(), 0, 40)
        })
    }).subscribe((data:PagedResultPatientPhotoModel) => {
                this.processPhotos(data)
            }).add(()=>console.log('unsubscribe happened'))
```

i'm curious as to why switchMap (and mergemap) worked each time but concatMap only worked once, seems like a bug in RXJS

I've decided to go with mergeMap since i feel like it's unlikely for the order the requests come back in to be wrong very often, and if so, it will correct itself after a few seconds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765322/angular2-switchmap-not-canceling-previous-http-calls - looks like switchmap can only cancel requests in the same underlying stream etc - doesn't propagate inward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not `switchMap`, which behaves in the manner you would expect. In the following snippet, the inner `interval` observable is unsubscribed when the subscription to the composed observable is unsubscribed:

```js
const source = new Rx.Subject();

const subscription = source
  .switchMap(() => {
    console.log('> switchmap');
    return Rx.Observable.interval(500);
  })
  .subscribe((value) => console.log(value));

source.next(1);
setTimeout(() => source.next(2), 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('> unsubscribe');
  subscription.unsubscribe();
}, 5000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Your problem lies with the calling of the subscription's `add` method. That creates an *additional* subscription and it is that subscription that's assigned to `sub`.

The initial subscription - to which you have added the additional subscription - is not assigned to a variable and is never unsubscribed. And it's that subscription that sees the `interval` continue to run.

The following snippet shows the problem:

```js
const source = new Rx.Subject();

const subscription1 = source
  .switchMap(() => {
    console.log('> switchmap');
    return Rx.Observable.interval(500);
  })
  .subscribe((value) => console.log(value));

const subscription2 = subscription1.add(() => console.log('> unsubscribed'));

source.next(1);
setTimeout(() => source.next(2), 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('> unsubscribe 2');
  subscription2.unsubscribe();
}, 5000);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('> unsubscribe 1');
  subscription1.unsubscribe();
}, 6000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Note that calling `unsubscribe` on `subscription1` will see `subscription2` unsubscribed, too - but not vice versa.

Comment: Ahh, right, I forgot i had added .add, and didn't realise .add returned a separate subscription. Confusing, thanks for clearing that up